# Dovecot not respecting log file?

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot

I'm installing Dovecot 2.0 and I am running into problems with it checking for new messages. Postfix is getting the messages but dovecot is not finding them.

In my dovecot.conf I am using a static userdb which checks my passdb using sql. When I start dovecot the log says it starts without error but does not mention anything about auth-worker connecting to my database. Looking at dovecot -n I can see that it is still trying to use PAM to authenticate despite it being commented out in the log:

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

No errors show up on the log right away but there are occasional errors that look like this:

```
localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Error: Timeout waiting for handshake from auth server. my pid=22714, input bytes=0
localhost dovecot: auth: Fatal: Support not compiled in for passdb driver 'pam'
localhost dovecot: master: Error: service(auth): command startup failed, throttling
```

I pastebinned the full log here: http://pastebin.com/c0VtFt2n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dovecot 2 the configuration files aren't the same - the values from your `dovecot.conf` file are probably being over-written. (Most online articles are written for dovecot 1.x, so be careful - go straight to the dovecot site for information, or ensure you have instructions specific for dovecot 2).

Check the `conf.d` directory (usually `/etc/dovecot/conf.d`, but might depend on how you installed) for the rest of the configuration files. PAM authentication is (I believe) in `auth-system.conf.ext`.

As you have noted, `dovecot -n` gives you the configuration dovecot reads. If you need to see a list of all settings, include the defaults, run `dovecot -a`.

Comment: I have a conf.d directory but it is empty. I tried copying the files in and reloading but it made no difference. I noticed dovecot -n lists my config being loaded from /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf. I don't think the log is being loaded at all because I've turned on all the addition logging options and there is no change.

Comment: a) did you check /usr/local/etc/dovecot/conf.d? b) You say that 'dovecot lists your config being loaded from...' is that the file you have been editing? c) Did you install by compiling or from a package manager? d) check which config is actually passed to dovecot in your init script (`/etc/init.d/dovecot` on some operating systems - around line 38 on the default script there is a line starting with 'config =' e) it would be helpful if you posted the output of `dovecot -n` f) once you confirm the config files being used, you will want to start simple and add (e.g. ssl) to the setup step by step

Comment: Found it! I totally didn't notice the config was in local. Thanks!